# my .htaccess is giving me a Forbidden error

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system

I have the following in the root directory of my site:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^./]{3}[^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The .htaccess should be redirecting any request 3 chars or longer without . in the string to the index.php/$string-text as to query my CMS db for output, however when i try and load the index page I get a 403 forbidden error... My .htaccess knowledge is quite basic so try and be easy with me! :)

Thanks

Ric

Comment: Is there anything else in the .htaccess file?

Comment: the weirdest part is that even if I solely have 'RewriteBase on' in the htaccess it still breaks the site with the 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Also here is my httpd.conf -> http://pastebin.com/s5hDv098

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be anything unexpected with your `.htaccess` file.  If the mod rewrite was not configured correctly, I would expect to see 404 errors or the user being redirected incorrectly.  As this does not appear to be the case; you need to widen your search to check that there are no security settings out of place.

I cannot see anything obvious in the httpd.conf file, but here are some of the steps you might want to take.

1. Remove the `.htaccess` file - if the website loads okay - then this file is causing an issue somehow; if it doesn't then there is something else wrong.
2. Check permissions on the web directory being used; there may be a permissions problem.
3. Check the httpd error log for suggestions.
4. Ask the question over at `serverfault.com` or poweruser stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So I found the issue, The apache error_log file explained I needed to add this into my .htaccess file and the httpd.conf file -> "Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" and it worked! Now to create my VHost and I am good to go!!! Thanks!!!!!

Thanks

Ric